# Multi database - each database writes to self and read from self

Tags: django, database, database-design, database-connection

tried to google as much as I could but couldn't find what I was looking for..

So idea is: There is one Master Database from which one you read users authentication process. And there is other many databases which ones keep information(her users, files and other) just to itself(it writes to itself and reads) but Master can reach them all. And if master makes changes to lets say to database structure - all fields should change but information on those database should stay (but master can change any of those database information).

It's like Multi-master but I do not want that other masters could reach other databases, but only write to itself.

Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

Question is not clear, but if you want use multiple databases with django. Look at THIShttps://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/multi-db/